# Rudin Theorem 2.40: choosing an $n$ by the Archimedean property

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I have a fairly small question on Rudin's proof of Theorem 2.40, which doesn't concern the overall result that $k$-cells are compact. Rudin comments that we can choose an $n$ so large that $2^{-n} \delta < r$; he states that if this weren't the case, then $2^n \leq \frac{\delta}{r}$ for every $n$, which contradicts the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is archimedean.

I'm trying to figure out how to map this statement back to the Archimedean property of $\mathbb{R}$ proved in the last chapter, which states that given $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x > 0$, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $nx > y$. I'm trying to figure out what exactly is my "$x$" and which is my $y$. It seems that the result is equivalent to choosing $n$ so that $2^n > \frac{\delta}{r}$. In this case, I believe we're taking $y = \frac{\delta}{r}$, $x = 2$, and the "$n$" we find is $2^{n-1}$.

Is this the correct understanding of this statement?

Comment: You're right that there's a technical inconsistency between Rudin's inequalities in that statement and the strict definition of Archimedean. There are various ways to resolve it; you've suggested one (and also $x=1$ and "$n$"${}=2^n$ works). Or we could simply find $n>(\log\frac\delta r)/\log 2$. Alternatively, one can use Archimedean to find $n>\frac\delta r$ and then use $2^n>n$. No matter what, one needs to use something about $2^n$ (or equivalently one needs to trust the meaning of the expression $(\log\frac\delta r)/\log 2$) to make this connection technically valid.

Comment: By the Binomial Theorem or by Induction we have n$<2^n $ for every $n\in\Bbb N.$ And with $x=1$ and $y=\delta /r$ we have $n=nx>y$ for some $n\in\Bbb N.$ So for some $n$ we have $2^n>n=nx>y=\delta /r.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we can choose an $n$ so large that $2^{-n} \delta < r$

> how to map this statement back to the Archimedean property of $\mathbb{R}$ proved in the last chapter, which states that given $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x > 0$, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $nx > y$. I'm trying to figure out what exactly is my "$x$" and which is my $y$.

$2^{-n} \delta < r$ is equivalent to $2^n > \frac{\delta}{r}$, which is again equivalent to, for example, $$n\ln 2 > \ln(\delta/r).$$
In this case $x=\ln 2$ and $y=\ln(\delta/r)$.